# How to pass in React request param into MySQL Statement?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I currently have an app, which displays certain data which is retrieved from a MySQL cloud database (JawsDB). I am having some difficulty passing in a specific field into my SQL statement.

It essentially retrieves the job from a dropdown menu, then uses axios to fetch the data from my database.

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async() => {
    const result = await axios.get('/submissions/${jobCategory}')
    setSubmissions(result.data.submissions)
  })()
}, [])
```

Here is the get request:

```
app.get('/submissions/:jobCategory', (req, res) => {
  sql_database.getSubmissionsCategory((error, submissions) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send({error: error.message});
      return
    }
    res.send({submissions});
  })
});
```

And finally, here is the sql statement:

```
function getSubmissionsCategory(callback) {

    const query = `
    SELECT * FROM submissions
    WHERE jobCategory="data analyst" 
    `

    connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            callback(error)
            return
        }
        callback(null, results)
    })
}
exports.getSubmissionsCategory = getSubmissionsCategory;
```

My code works when I manually specify the specific job type such as above. My question is now that I have passed in the jobCategory into axis, how do I dynamically update my SQL statement according to what is being passed in?

E.g. I pass in "Software Engineer", I would like the SQL statement to be :
SELECT * FROM submissions
WHERE jobCategory="Software Engineer"

Comment: Try `console.log()`ing the value of `jobCategory`. Might be an issue there.

Comment: @LakshayaU. my jobCategory is passing in the correct value, I just do not know how to set the value passed in into my SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value stored in `jobCategory` to the `getSubmissionsCategory` function. Then you need to alter the query based on your request.

For example:

```js
app.get('/submissions/:jobCategory', (req, res) => {
  sql_database.getSubmissionsCategory(req.params.jobCategory, (error, submissions) => {
    // ...
  }
})
function getSubmissionsCategory(jobCategory, callback) {
  // ...
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?", [jobCategory], callback)
  // ...
}
```

If you are using the npm package mysql, take a look at [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries) about performing queries with variables. (or for [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#first-query)).

Comment: Thanks! I modified my axios call by adding a param jobCategory, then used req.query.jobCategory to get my value. For some reason, I cannot pass in ${jobCategory}.

Comment: @dfwgwefewfwe You should use ` (backtick) for string interpolation: ```await axios.get(`/submissions/${jobCategory}`)```